# What is the simplest way to control the opacity of block fill in `nicematrix`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, nicematrix

I am trying to control the opacity of blocks background fills. I tried the following

1. `\pgfsetfillopacity{<transparency level>}`, which controls the opacity of the entire array drawn by `nicematrix`
2. Setting the transparency with `\tikzset{style=<transparency level>}`
3. `opacity={<transparency level>}`

None worked

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
        
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin]
        \Block[fill=Coral3]{3-3}<\large>{Z} &               &   &   0    \\
                                            & \hspace*{1cm} &   & \Vdots \\
                                            &               &   &   0    \\ \hline
                         0                  &    \Cdots     & 0 &   0
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally opacity is used to draw partially overlapping shapes, but that does not seem to be the case in your example. What exactly do you want the output to be, i.e., what kind of transparency are you looking for?

Comment: Note that if you just want a lighter fill of the same color you can use something like `fill=Coral3!15`.

Comment: I want the filling of `\Block` command to be transparent. I am rather learning `nicematrix` than simply trying to do something specific

Comment: I just wanted to point out that transparency is only a meaningful concept if something is put over something else, like in the answer of François below where the text is shown behind the node or the line in the second example of the answer of Simon. If you don't have any overlapping objects then transparency is equivalent to just a lighter color.

Comment: @Marijn. I was just trying to test this and noted your answer is entirely correct. It is still good to be able to get the same result in different methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comamnd `\Block`, you have a key `fill` (to fill the block) but you have also a key `tikz`. The rectangle corresponding to the block will be used in Tikz with the Tikz keys provided by the value of that key.

Here, I have used `tikz={fill=Coral3,opacity = 0.5}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz,xcolor}
        
\begin{document}

Some text text some text some text some text 
\hspace{-4cm}
$\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin]
    \Block[tikz={fill=Coral3,opacity = 0.5}]{3-3}<\large>{Z} 
             &               &   &   0    \\
             & \hspace*{1cm} &   & \Vdots \\
             &               &   &   0    \\ \hline
         0   &    \Cdots     & 0 &   0
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above]

Comment: You need at least PGF version 3.1.6 of 2020-09-29.

Comment: Is the use of tikz inside Block a documented feature?

Comment: @Simon Dispa: The key `tikz` for the command `\Block` has been added in the version 5.19 of 2021-07-23. In the current version of the documentation `nicematrix.pdf`, it is documented p.5.

Comment: Nice. Thank you.